# Error on Magento 1.9.2.2 running with Redis cache

Tags: magento-1.9, home, redis, product-linking

I tried to migrate the pacmall.net server to my local WAMP machine because I installed the Redis server on my Windows 8 system and Redis client extensions on the WAMP.

I was able to see the frontend home page and backend.

When I clicked any link on the home page, I got the following error message:

```
The requested URL /apparel-shoe-jewelry/jewelry-watches/watches was not found on the server.
```

Does any of you know what cause the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled rewrites in your webserver?

http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/mod_rewrite-windows-apache-url-rewriting

If so... Do you have the .htaccess file in the root of the project?

Comment: Thanks.  The .htaccess was missing because pacmall.net is running on Nignx and does not have the .htaccess.  Thanks again!!

Comment: If this helped you then you'd accept the answer as valid. That's how this page works ;)